# airflow dynamically generating tasks with branchpython operator

Tags: dynamic, task, airflow

Currently we are running the following kind of dags.

```
  t1 >> t2 >> [ t3, t4 ] 
  t4 >> t6 
  t3 >> t5 >>t6
```

We receive files of same structure from different clients and process the data with one dag for each client.
But the tasks are similar. Only the source and destination locations are differnt. t2 is just checking if files exist. If yes, then executes spark else sends a notification and ends.

I tried dynamically creating the tasks using a for loop as following.

```
def t2(client,**kwargs): 
     return PythonOperator(task_id='t2_'+client, python_callable=t1func,...)

####other functions for t2,t3 etc t6 

t1=DummyOperator(taskid='t1',dag=dag) 
t6=DummyOperator(taskid='t6',dag=dag) 

for c in client_list: 
    t1 >> t2(i) >> [t3(i),t4(i)] 
    t3(i) >> t5(i) >> t6 
    t4(i) >> t6
```

In the for loop step 2 and three are not working. The tasks t5, t6 are shown as tasks without any predecessors.

I expect the dag to be

```
t1 >> t2_cl1 >> [t3_cl1,t4_cl1]
t3_cl1 >> t5_cl1 >> t6
t4_cl1 >> t6
t1 >> t2_cl2 >> [t3_cl2,t4_cl1]
t3_cl2 >> t5_cl2 >> t6
t4_cl2 >> t6
```

Could you please suggest me a solution.

Comment: I wonder this DAG has error on importing.  you cannot do `t3(i)` twice in a for loop.  unless `t3` function is generating random task ID.  This will produce task_id duplication error.   you need to have something like `t3_temp = t3(c)` (I think it is c? instead of i) and `>> [t3_temp, t4_temp]` and `t3_temp >> t5(c) >> t6`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not specify DAG in the dynamically created tasks. You should either add dag explicitely in the operators or wrap your whole task creation in `with DAG(..)`:

Comment: Thanks for your idea on this. I did not get any import errors. At the same time, I realized, there is no need of branch python operator here. In the for loop itself I checked the condition and generated tasks accordingly.